# jwt-auth token has expired

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt

I am utilizing jwt-auth and vue-auth for my SPA. For testing purposes, I have the refreshData variable in the config file for vue-auth set to 1 for refreshing every minute. For the jwt-auth config file, I have the ttl set to 1 and the refresh_ttl set to 3.

I am able to login and receive a token. I see it in the localStorage. Every minute for the first 3 minutes, I get a success for the refresh, and I see the token changing in localStorage, but the 4th time, I get an error.

```
{message: "Token has expired and can no longer be refreshed",…}
exception: "Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException"
```

Why is this? Since I am refreshing the token, I thought that the refresh_ttl wouldn't even matter, but it certainly seems to be dictating this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and having tried everything I could find on the net, nothing wanted to work. So I studied the **config/jwt.php** file on my own and solved it by modifying this line of the file :

```
'refresh_ttl' => env ('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),
```

by :

```
'refresh_ttl' => env ('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', Null),
```

Previously, I also modified this line :

```
'ttl' => env ('JWT_TTL', 60),
```

by :

```
'ttl' => env ('JWT_TTL', NULL),
```

Hope it helps other people :) .

Answer (score 2):

in your AuthController try to change

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
```

into

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to expire your token then in config jwt.php replace

```
 'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),


 'required_claims' => [
        'iss',
        'iat',
        // 'exp',
        'nbf',
        'sub',
        'jti',
    ],
```

then hit this command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In your auth controller refresh function please to change:

```
return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "payload" => [
            'access_token' => auth()->refresh(),
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]
    ]);
```

And you need to change your config/auth.php like this:

```
    'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

And here is a good example [laravel-jwt-vuejs](https://github.com/furkankadioglu/SimpleCalendarExample-Web-Application)

Answer (score 0):

You can set ttl to null, to yield a never expiring token.

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),
```

or directly give in .env

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using that package. What you can do is set the expiration time in the config/jwt.php file to 7 days so if a user authenticates the token will expire after 7 days.

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60*24*7),
```

The value is in minutes.